# jQuery return onClick

Tags: jquery

I want to know if is it possible to do the same javascript code with Jquery:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="javascript:return CheckPasswords()" />
```

What it does is return true or false on user click.

With Jquery I would write:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#btnSalvar").click(function(){
       if([...])
       {
         return false;
       }
         return true;
       });
}
```

But i dont know in case return false it would have the same effect.

**UPDATED:**Solution is

```
$("btnSalvar").click(function(e){

    if([...])
    {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
```

thk you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it returning false should have the same result whether done in javascript or jquery

```
$('#btnSalvar').click(function(){ return CheckPasswords(); });
```

should operate the same way as your onclick event in jquery

Comment: no,i dont think so man."javascript:return false", block any additional event of button to fire.

Comment: you know what, your absolutely right, don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Since the parameter to the `click` function is a closure, the return value is lost. Try something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnSalvar").click(function(){
         window.val = [...];
    }
});
\\ Do what you want with val here
```

Of course, if possible avoid assigning variables to the global namespace, but without further information on what you're trying to do, it's the only thing that you can guarantee will work.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like you're asking what "return false" does here, is that right? "return false" will prevent action on the click - so it's essentially the same as event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation(). Essentially, nothing will happen at all.